# How to read local file into string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to read a (svg) file in Angular 6 from assets into a string.
I tried things like that:

```html
                this._htmlClient.get('../../assets/images/chart1.svg').subscribe(data => {
                    console.log('svg-file: ', data);
                });
```

But it does not work. The console.log is not written and I get a error

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/images/chart1.svg", ok: false,

The path is right. When i copy it into the browser I see my picture.

**How I can get the file content into a string?**

Answer (score 3):

By default, the HttpClient expects the response to be JSON. If you want to get something else, you need to specify the type:

```
this._htmlClient.get('path', { responseType: 'text' })
  .subscribe(data => { console.log(data) });
```

[HttpClient - Requesting Non-JSON Data](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)